# Visual Studio Debug two Instances

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

When I try to debug my WPF application in visual studio 2010 it launches two versions of my application. Both are linked to the debugger. has anyone seen this before or knows a way to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have 2 separate projects in your solution?

Comment: What do you see on the debug tab in Project Properties?

Comment: I have three projects (wpf,wcf, azure) in my solution. It is launching the same WPF project twice. In the debug tab I just have  it selected to start project

Comment: If I run a clean and try to debug i get an error about the debug target is missing. If I build then debug that error goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually have multiple startup projects in a VS solution, so it could be that your application was somehow added twice.

Right-click on the solution and select `Set Startup Projects...`. Ensure in this dialog that you have the `Single startup project` radio button selected and that the dropdown is pointing to your project.

If this is currently how your app is setup, I would select a different project, save, then reselect your current project in the hope that maybe VS will clear out any incorrect config.

Note that this information is stored in the `.suo` file associated with your solution, so another possible solution is to close the solution, delete this file, and reopen the solution. I have had more than one inexplicable problem fixed by deleting this file.